# How do I verify if a string is correctly formated?

Tags: racket

I've been asked to write a program that verifies if a string is in the following format:

```
"<number><number><number><number><-><number><number><number><space><capitalized word/sentence>"
```

It should return #t when the requirements are met and #f when they are not.

I've tried using the following code

```
(define (verify codpos)
      (cond ((string<=? (substring codpos 0 4) "9999")
             (string=? (substring codpos 4 5) "-")
             (string<=? (substring codpos 5 8) "999")
             (string=? (substring codpos 8 9) " ")
             (string>? (substring codpos 9 (string-length codpos)) "9")
             (string<? (substring codpos 9 (string-length codpos)) "a") #t)
            (else #f)))
```

It indicates #t every case, being the conditions met or not.
I would appreciate any form of help. I've just recently gotten into programming and I can't wrap my head around an exercise this simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use regular expressions to achieve this:

```
#lang racket

(define (verify-rexpr s)
  (regexp-match? #px"^\\d{4}-\\d{3} (\\p{Lu}|\\s)*$" s))


(module+ test
  (require rackunit)
  ; -- 
  (check-true (verify-rexpr "1234-321 "))
  (check-false (verify-rexpr "1234-0s1 "))
  (check-true (verify-rexpr "9999-999 WORD"))
  (check-false (verify-rexpr "1234-321 word"))
  (check-true (verify-rexpr "1234-321 ALL CAPS SENTENCE"))
  (check-false (verify-rexpr "1234-321 Not ALL CAPS SENTENCE")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand capitalized word/sentence mean "capitalized word with sentence" or "capitalized word or sentence" or "first string capitalized sentence" or "first string capitalized and length can be one". "Sentence with symbol" or "not allow orther symbol".

If you want this "1234-123 THIS IS SENSTANCE WITH SYMBOL- AND NUMBER123."

```lisp
#lang racket

(define (varify str)
  (and (>= (string-length str) 10)
       (number? (string->number (substring str 0 4)))
       (string=? (substring str 4 5) "-")
       (number? (string->number (substring str 5 8)))
       (string=? (substring str 8 9) " ")
       (not (string=? (string-upcase (substring str 9 10))
                      (string-downcase (substring str 9 10))))
       (string=? (string-upcase (substring str 9))
                 (substring str 9))))

(varify "1234-123 THIS IS SENSTANCE WITH SYMBOL - @AND NUMBER123.") ; #true
(varify "1234-123 T") ; #true
(varify "1234-123 ") ; #false
(varify "1234-123 !HIS IS ENSTANCE WITH SYMBOL - @AND NUMBER123.") ; #false
(varify "1234-123  HIS IS SENSTANCE WITH SYMBOL - @AND NUMBER123.") ; #false
(varify "1234-123 tHIS IS SENSTANCE WITH SYMBOL - @AND NUMBER123.") ; #false
(varify "1234-12a THIS IS SENSTANCE WITH SYMBOL - @AND NUMBER123.") ; #false
```

Comment: That's insanely good, thank you a lot.
It's also quite simple! Thanks you really helped me out!